# SQL: How to use a column that was just added

Tags: sql

I am trying to add 2 columns and then I would like to set some values to them but I get a compile-error saying the column does not exist. I am using the following script:

```
IF @LogProcessed = 0
Begin

IF NOT EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'SYSTM_FRM' and column_name = 'SF_Ip_TXT')
ALTER TABLE SYSTM_FRM add SF_Ip_TXT NVARCHAR(20)

IF NOT EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'SYSTM_FRM' and column_name = 'SF_Port_NUM')
ALTER TABLE SYSTM_FRM add SF_Port_NUM int


IF  (EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'FRM' and column_name = 'FRM_Ip_TXT') AND
    EXISTS (select column_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.columns where table_name = 'FRM' and column_name = 'FRM_Ip_TXT'))
begin
Update dbo.SYSTM_FRM
SET     dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Ip_TXT = dbo.FRM.FRM_Ip_TXT,
        dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Port_NUM = dbo.FRM.FRM_Port_NUM

FROM dbo.FRM INNER JOIN dbo.SYSTM_FRM ON dbo.FRM.FRM_RCRD_NUM = dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_FrameRecord_NUM          

ALTER TABLE FRM DROP COLUMN FRM_Ip_TXT
ALTER TABLE FRM DROP COLUMN FRM_Port_NUM  
  end


Update [Update_Log]
Set Update_Log_Processed = 1
Where [Update_Log_Version] = '00001'
```

end

Is there any way to use a column that I am adding in the same script?

Comment: I updated the code. Why can't I put a GO within a Begin-End statement?

Comment: The GO statement ends the current batch of code. A BEGIN-END block is a single entity, so it has to be completed within the batch of code.

Comment: I don't know if this was intentional or not, but your IF statement checks the same condition twice when checking INFORMATION_SCHEMA. Is that a cut-and-paste error?

Comment: Yep, Copy-Paste error, thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you cannot save it in a proc like that

example

```
create table TestAdd2 (id int)
go
```

You cannot create this procedure

```
create proc prTest as

insert TestAdd2 values (1)

exec ('ALTER TABLE TestAdd2 add SF_Port_NUM int')

update TestAdd2 set id = 1,SF_Port_NUM = 2

select * from TestAdd2

GO
```

You get this error
`Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Procedure prTest, Line 7
Invalid column name 'SF_Port_NUM'.`

This is because at parse time the column does not exist

However if you use dynamic SQL for the update you are good to go

```
create proc prTest2 as

insert TestAdd2 values (1)

exec ('ALTER TABLE TestAdd2 add SF_Port_NUM int')

exec ('update TestAdd2 set id = 1,SF_Port_NUM = 2')

select * from TestAdd2

GO
```

in your case your update statement would be

```
exec('Update dbo.SYSTM_FRM
SET     dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Ip_TXT = dbo.FRM.FRM_Ip_TXT,
        dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Port_NUM = dbo.FRM.FRM_Port_NUM
FROM dbo.FRM INNER JOIN dbo.SYSTM_FRM 
ON dbo.FRM.FRM_RCRD_NUM = dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_FrameRecord_NUM')
```

Comment: you need dynamic sql in your update statement as well because of parse time compilation problems

Comment: What'ss the purpose of this line: 'update TestAdd2 set id = 1,SF_Port_NUM = 2'

Comment: It is an example that you can run so that you can see how it works, in your case it would be exec('Update dbo.SYSTM_FRM
SET     dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Ip_TXT = dbo.FRM.FRM_Ip_TXT,
        dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_Port_NUM = dbo.FRM.FRM_Port_NUM
FROM dbo.FRM INNER JOIN dbo.SYSTM_FRM ON dbo.FRM.FRM_RCRD_NUM = dbo.SYSTM_FRM.SF_FrameRecord_NUM')

Answer (score 4):

Put a `GO` in between

Comment: There is a problem. The whole code is in an IF statement, so when I add GO in between, it gives syntax errors. The whole code is in between BEGIN and END.

Answer (score 0):

All DDL statements should follow the statement seperator GO in order to make use of it